# XML data scanner with Ruby: case statement or dynamic dispatch in term of performance?

Tags: ruby, performance, xml-parsing

I'm writing a XML data scanner which read XML text using some XML parser library like nokogiri or such,
and generate a tree of nodes. I need to create an object per a XML element.
So, I need a method which creates an object according to given element name and attributes, like this, 
regardless of kind of the parser library options (either SAX or DOM) I'm using:

```
create_node(name, attributes_hash)
```

This method need to branch according to the `name`. Implementation possibilities are:

1. Case statement
2. Method dispatch and pre-defined methods

Since this method possibly become a bottleneck,  I wrote a benchmark script to check how Ruby perform. (The benchmark script attached at last part of this question. I don't like some part of the script -- particularly how to create case statement --, so  *comments* to how I can improve this is also welcome, but please provide it as comments not an answer... I probably need to create a question for that too..).

The script measures following four cases, in two range sizes:

1. method dispatch with constant name
2. method dispatch with name concatenate with `#{}`
3. method dispatch with name concatenate with `+`
4. using case statement, call the same methods

Results:

```
                                                 user     system      total        real
a to z: method_calls (with const name)       0.090000   0.000000   0.090000 (  0.092516)
a to z: method_calls (with dynamic name) 1   0.180000   0.000000   0.180000 (  0.181793)
a to z: method_calls (with dynamic name) 2   0.200000   0.000000   0.200000 (  0.202818)
a to z: switch_calls                         0.130000   0.000000   0.130000 (  0.132633)

                                                user     system      total        real
a to zz: method_calls (with const name)       2.900000   0.000000   2.900000 (  2.894273)
a to zz: method_calls (with dynamic name) 1   6.500000   0.010000   6.510000 (  6.507099)
a to zz: method_calls (with dynamic name) 2   6.980000   0.000000   6.980000 (  6.987534)
a to zz: switch_calls                         4.750000   0.000000   4.750000 (  4.742448)
```

I observe const name based method dispatch is faster than using case statement, however, if string operation is involved when determine the method name, the costs to determine the method name costs more than actual method call costs, effectively make these options(2 and 3) slower than option 4. Also, the difference between option 2 and 3 are negligible.

To make the scanner secure, I prefer to have some prefix to the methods, since without that, it is possible to craft a XML to invoke some methods, which I don't want to happen. But the cost to determine the method name is not negligible.

How do you write these scanner? I want to know an answer to following questions:

1. Is there any good scheme other than above?
2. If not, which (case-when or method dispatch) scheme you choose?
3. If I don't compute method name, it is faster. Is there any good way to do method dispatch securely? (by limiting node name to be called, for example.)

### The benchmark script

```
# Benchmark to measure the difference of
# use of case statement and message passing

require 'benchmark'

def bench(title, tobj, count)
  Benchmark.bmbm do |b|
    b.report "#{title}: method_calls (with const name)" do
      (1..count).each do |c|
        tobj.run_send_using_const
      end
    end

    b.report "#{title}: method_calls (with dynamic name) 1" do
      (1..count).each do |c|
        tobj.run_send_using_dynamic_1
      end
    end

    b.report "#{title}: method_calls (with dynamic name) 2" do
      (1..count).each do |c|
        tobj.run_send_using_dynamic_2
      end
    end

    b.report "#{title}: switch_calls" do
      (1..count).each do |c|
        tobj.run_switch
      end
    end
  end
end


class Switcher
  def initialize(names)
    @method_names = { }
    @names = names
    names.each do |n|
      @method_names[n] = "dynamic_#{n}"
      @@n = n
      class << self
        mname = "dynamic_#{@@n}"
        define_method(mname) do
          mname
        end
      end
    end

    swst = ""
    names.each do |n|
      swst << "when \"#{n}\" then dynamic_#{n}\n"
    end

    st = "
    def run_switch_each(n)
      case n
#{swst}
      end
    end
    "
    eval(st)
  end

  def run_send_using_const
    @method_names.each_value do |n|
      self.send n
    end
  end

  def run_send_using_dynamic_1
    @names.each do |n|
      self.send "dynamic_#{n}"
    end
  end

  def run_send_using_dynamic_2
    @names.each do |n|
      self.send "dynamic_" + n
    end
  end

  def run_switch
    @names.each do |n|
      run_switch_each(n)
    end
  end

end


sw1 = Switcher.new('a'..'z')
sw2 = Switcher.new('a'..'zz')

bench("a to z", sw1, 10000)
bench("a to zz", sw2, 10000)
```

Comment: Just being curious: Why do you write your own XML parser? You may look into an existing library like Nokogiri.

Comment: I agree with padde. There are quite a few high performance XML parser libs for Ruby that contains fast C/C++ code or link with C/C++-libs.

Comment: Thank you very much for comments. Now I understand the question is misleading. I didn't mean to build a passer from scratch. I want to write a data scanner using XML parser, my question is regard to that kind of scanner. I will modify the question to reflect that later today.

Comment: I'm confused - if you're a the point where you're benchmarking solutions to your problem, what are you actually asking?

Comment: I'm for case statement; since you care about performance, better options don't come in my mind.

Comment: It looks like I need clarify the actual question. thanks.

Comment: If I only have options like above, I'm for case statement too, since it's perform well. But is there any better options other than above?

Comment: You can make `send` private on the dispatching class and use `public_send` instead of `send` to limit the dispatched calls to public methods only. That would be a little slower than the simple `send`, but aesthetically nicer than using prefixed methods.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a case of premature optimization.

> But the cost to determine the method name is not negligible.

Non-negligible compared to what? The approaches here have different performance numbers, but will the time taken to dispatch one node be comparable to what it takes to parse the node (with Nokogiri or etc), to construct the specialized node object, and do whatever you need with it?

I believe it won't. I don't have a benchmark to prove that statement (you need actual code for that), but the fact that string concatenation vs string interpolation actually makes a noticeable difference in the results (dynamic1 vs dynamic2) is a good indicator that you're measuring something trivial.

Or that adding one string concatenation per dispatch increases the resulting time 2-2.5 times (const vs dynamic2).

Comment: I think I'm not asking question well. The negligible part of the computing cost is, as you said, difference between how to determine method name. But you said, "it is noticeable difference, but measuring something trivial?" If you mean, the difference between two dynamic cases are negligible, I agree. But the point is -- since how I asked my question was wrong -- whether switch, method dispatch(with dynamic name) OR *other* possible scheme to do this efficiently. (Thank you very much anyway)

Comment: Let me rephrase. 1) The difference in performance between string concatenation and string interpolation is only visible in microbenchmarks. But look, here we're seeing it make a visible difference in the numbers (0.02s and 0.5s). 2) The only difference between the highest performing and lowest performing options is 1 (!) string concatenation, with short strings, per dispatch. And it actually increases the benchmarked time ~2.2 times. That basically guarantees that everything you're measuring here takes very little time, and won't make a difference once you add the business logic.

Comment: No, it's not negligible. I need to find a solution which performs better even a tiny amount of difference.

I haven't stated that the method might be called large number of times. If it is only called < 10K times(just a example), may be it's not a issue. The reason why asking this here even with a bounty is, I prefer to reduce the cost as far as possible, since I process large XML file with lot of nodes which require to use the method, and I need to process the files in interactive manner (I'm editing the large file and process, wait and see, say, every 5min) so speed is not negligible.